# proper methodology for abstracting smaller class from larger class in c#

Tags: c#

I have a class, Projections, which maps to a table of the same name, which has 14 properties(columns). Most of the time I only need 5 of those properties. What is the proper way to create a smaller class that only inherits the properties I need in C#. I'm a VB guy who is trying to migrate to C# and can't seem to find exactly what I am trying to do online.

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on interfaces as that sounds like a better approach than coupling classes. There are many great books that deal with designing classes, interfaces, and models, but here's a quick link to get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b5b8ezk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch it around and create a class with less columns and then make your class with the full set of column inherit from that class and add the extra columns.